# Reading from Kinect Camera rather than the default webcam to detect objects in the frame

Tags: python, opencv, kinect, webcam, video-capture

I have found two sample codes that accomplish separate tasks that I am trying to get to work in tandem.

The Fist code opens the webcam from my laptop and reads the video stream to detect a certain colored object within the frame. It then creates an outline of the circular object and creates a colored trail of it previous location as it moves in real time.

The only issue is I am trying to use an Xbox 360 Kinect to work as the webcam rather than the built-in webcam on my laptop. (In the future I plan on using the depth camera as well, which is why I would like to use the kinect camera.)

The second code shows how to open and view the Kinect Camera's videostream.

I have found that setting the number in the `VideoStream(src= 0).start()` to `0` is the default camera. If I were to change that value to say a 1, 2, 3 or whatever... it should read the next available camera. However, when I print all available cameras, it only shows the webcam listed.

I have deleted, reinstalled, and installed all the correct drivers and packages that I should need for this to work if I were to just put a #1 in that line of code but have had no luck. There must be a different approach that will work to solve this issue.

## ---------The First Code------------------------------------------------

````py
# import the necessary packages
from collections import deque
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import imutils
import time

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
    help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=64,
    help="max buffer size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# define the lower and upper boundaries of the "green"
# ball in the HSV color space, then initialize the
# list of tracked points
greenLower = (53, 36, 124)
greenUpper = (200, 200, 242)
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])

# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
# to the webcam
if not args.get("video", False): #if not video file was given
    vs = VideoStream(src=0).start() #access the webcam here

# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

# allow the camera or video file to warm up
time.sleep(2.0)

# keep looping
while True:
    # grab the current frame
    frame = vs.read()

    # handle the frame from VideoCapture or VideoStream
    frame = frame[1] if args.get("video", False) else frame

    # if we are viewing a video and we did not grab a frame,
    # then we have reached the end of the video
    if frame is None:
        break

    # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
    # color space
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # construct a mask for the color "green", then perform
    # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
    # blobs left in the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

    # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
    # (x, y) center of the ball
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    center = None

    # only proceed if at least one contour was found
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
        # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
        # centroid
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

        # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
        if radius > 10:
            # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
            # then update the list of tracked points
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # update the points queue
    pts.appendleft(center)
        # loop over the set of tracked points
    for i in range(1, len(pts)):
        # if either of the tracked points are None, ignore
        # them
        if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
            continue

        # otherwise, compute the thickness of the line and
        # draw the connecting lines
        thickness = int(np.sqrt(args["buffer"] / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
        cv2.line(frame, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)

    # show the frame to our screen
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break


# close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#----------End of the First code-----------------------------------



#------------Second Code-------------------------------------------

from pykinect import nui
import numpy
import cv2

def video_handler_function(frame):

    video = numpy.empty((480,640,4),numpy.uint8)
    frame.image.copy_bits(video.ctypes.data)

    cv2.imshow('KINECT Video Stream', video)


kinect = nui.Runtime()
kinect.video_frame_ready += video_handler_function
kinect.video_stream.open(nui.ImageStreamType.Video, 2,nui.ImageResolution.Resolution640x480,nui.ImageType.Color)

cv2.namedWindow('KINECT Video Stream', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

while True:

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27: break

kinect.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#----------end of the second code---------------------------------

```python

When I change the value, to 1 which is the port number that the kinect is connected to, it should open the video stream and have the same results as the first code, but it just closes the python app.
````